# Read data from excel spreadsheet in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have written code for reading data from excel sheet in Selenium. Login scenarios is working properly, App is taking login's data from excel sheet. Now I have to define that code globally, so I can enter data data in different sheets of excel-sheet for various scenarios. Can you anyone guide me for this scenario.

Comment: If I understand right, just create reader/parser class/method which read this sheets. In this class, you can exciting random test data on every run, like parse data in the collection, then iterate over it with random generators, take this random data and pars it in your tests(just quick brainstorming).